# Loop for resources

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops, resources

I'm looking for a solution for my problem with automatic connection ImageView with a proper JPG from resources.
I have a simple array with names of gods like:

```
final String[] godslist = {"Achilles", "Agni", "Ah Muzen Cab", "Ah Puch", "Amaterasu", "Anhur", "Anubis", "Ao Kuang", "Aphrodite", "Apollo", "Arachne", "Ares", "Artemis", "Artio"}

final ImageView godImage = findViewById(R.id.godImage);
final TextView godName = findViewById(R.id.nameOfGod);

int randomGod = (int) (Math.random() * 14);
godName.setText(godslist[randomGod]);
```

And for now, it's working fine. In the TextView I get the random name of a god from the array.
The problem is with connecting chosen god with his image. I thought about a loop that will search resources by name of chosen god e.g. "Achilles". In resources, I have a file named "achilles.jpg" e.t.c., so it should be *godName.setImageResource(R.drawable.achilles);*. Not every god's name is consisting of one word only - like "Ah Muzen Cab" and drawable can't be named with spaces (but this is not a big problem for now). For some reasons drawable can't also be named starting with an uppercase character, so I probably need to do something like this:

```
godName.setText(godName.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
```

And then I should use some loop to find the name in resources. Below code should be easiest, if it would work like that, but...

```
godImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.(godName.setText(godName.getText().toString().toLowerCase())));
```

The same problem is with sounds from resources (depending on which god is randomly chosen), but it will be easier when I figure out how set images. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can incapsulate data in a separate class, and use its instances when randomly choosing an array index:

```
public class GodData {
        public final String name;
        public final String imageResId;
        public final String soundResId;

        public GodData(String name, String imageResId, String soundResId) {
            this.name = name;
            this.imageResId = imageResId;
            this.soundResId = soundResId;
        }
    }

final GodData[] godslist = {new GodData("Achilles", R.drawable.achilles, R.raw.achilles_sound), ...}

GodData randomGod = godslist((int) (Math.random() * 14));
godName.setText(randomGod.name);
godImage.setImageResource(randomGod. imageResId);
```